# Error when combining python script in a bash for loop

Tags: python, bash

Warning: very new to python

I am trying to connect to a series of IP addresses stored in an array ${INSTANCE_IPS[@]}. I am trying to use a for loop to use a python script to call an API to each IP address in the array.

However, when trying to run the below script I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 12, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'str'
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 12, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'str'
```

I'm sure I could do a for loop in python but I haven't learnt that yet and for the moment just need to get this working. It runs fine if I only use one IP address from the array.

```
for instance in ${INSTANCE_IPS[@]}
do
  echo "Connecting to $instance"

  /usr/bin/python << END_OF_PYTHON

  import requests
  import json
  import sys
  import socket
  import fnmatch
  import os

  ipaddress = os.getenv('instance')
  print ipaddress

  port = ':80'
  updatedipaddress = ipaddress +port
  print 'updated ip address is ' + updatedipaddress

  add_node = updatedipaddress

  print 'add_node is ' + add_node

  url = 'https://' + os.getenv('instance') + ':9070/api/tm/1.0/config/active/pools/' + 'aol_http'
  print 'url is ' + url
  jsontype = {'content-type': 'application/json'}
  client = requests.Session()
  client.auth = ('username', 'password')
  client.verify = 0

  response = client.get(url)
  print response
  pools = json.loads(response.content)
  nodes = pools['properties']['basic']['nodes']

  data = nodes
  data.append(unicode(add_node))

  client.put(url,json.dumps(pools), headers=jsontype)
  END_OF_PYTHON
done
```

Any help with figuring out where I am going wrong would be appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: `END_OF_PYTHON` may not be indented (unless by one or more tabs and you use `<<-END_OF_PYTHON` as the beginning of the here document).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The bash variable `instance` is not passed on to subprocesses. You have to export it before starting the python code. This can be seen in the error message about `ipaddress + port` as ipdadress is of NoneType meaning that `os.getenv()` did not work.

```
for instance in ${INSTANCE_IPS[@]}
do
  echo "Connecting to $instance"
  export instance

  /usr/bin/python << END_OF_PYTHON
   [...]
```

Comment: Or he could use the shell variable directly in the heredoc, like `url = 'https://${instance}:9070/....`